# Listen property while using change notifiers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

This was the code which i tried to execute. In the MyTextField class i mentioned listen property to false, but as soon as i type something on the text field, i can see the changes in my appbar and my text widget. What could be the reason for such output. I hope when listen property is false, it shouldnt listen anything, but i can listen to changes only after mentioning it to false. Without listen property, i couldn't find any change in my appbar and text widget when i give an input in textfield

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data = 'Secret message';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context)=> Data(),
          child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: MyText(),
          ),
          body: Level1(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:Level2(),
    );
  }
}

class Level2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: [
        MyTextField(),
        Level3()
      ],),
    );
  }
}

class Level3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).data),
    );
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      Provider.of<Data>(context,listen: false).data
    );
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newText){
        **Provider.of<Data>(context,listen: false).changeString(newText);**
      },
    );
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier{
  String data = 'Dummy data';
  void changeString(String newString){
    data = newString;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: you didn't set listen to false on the text widget, why do you expect it to "not change" when the value of text field changes?

Comment: i want it to change. but when i execute this program,my text widget listens to textfield, inspite of listen false